# Using SSL certificate with C# and MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

Im using C# to connect to MySQL from a remote host that is on a different machine from  the MySQL server. Here is the code:

```
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder db = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        db.Server = "1.2.3.4";
        db.Port = "3306";

        db.UserID = "jerry";
        db.Password = "jerrypassword"; 
        db.Database = "wordpress";
        db.CertificateFile = certificatePathToPem;    // path to PEM certificate
        db.CertificatePassword = certificatePassword;  // PEM certificate password

        string MySqlConnectionString = db.ToString();
        controllerInfo.myCon = new MySqlConnection(MySqlConnectionString);

        if (controllerInfo.myCon != null) {
            MyUtil.WriteLine("login in SQL.....");
            try {
                controllerInfo.myCon.Open();
                MyUtil.WriteLine("....sql opened");
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                MyUtil.WriteLine("....sql NOT opened!!");
            }
```

As you can see, im trying to connect using SSL certificate. But the connection is always refused. Before i try using SSL it connects with no problem.

On the MySql server im using phpmyadmin to configure everything, in the user privileges in phpmyadmin i click the box that says "REQUIRE SSL", but of course it refuses the connection. I also dont see anywhere to give it a certificate file or path, not sure how it all works. I have it so that it only accepts connection from my remote hosts IP address.

I also see in the password section on phpmyadmin where it says to select to use either SHA256 password Authentication, or NATIVE MySql password Authentication, I tried both and none works.

Does anybody know whats wrong? Do I even need to use SSL with talking to the database from a remote host securely?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is an exception thrown (e.g., from `myCon.Open()`)? If so, please include the full exception details: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/
If your DB is configured to _only_ allow connections from your web server's IP address then it may be OK to not use SSL; there's a small risk that someone with access to the network could read data from your database going over the network, but they should not be able to log in or modify data.

Answer (score -2):

Try [this](http://www.sqlservermart.com/HowTo/Windows_Import_Certificate.aspx) on both the SQL server and the client machine then delete your certificate code

Comment: Thanks i will try it, oh im running apache web server on bitnami on windows

Comment: I went through all the steps, but im wondering How does MySql know anything about this certificate? if i dont add the certificate to the above code, how do i know its using SSL and is encrypted?

Comment: I have REQUIRE SSL turned on for the remote account im trying to access in MySQL, when i try to connect using the above code (without the certificate) it said error authentication failed using method "mysql_native_password"

Comment: Link is dead, so answer is of no help.